# How to get the label text from asp:FileUpload and display in a Label using ASP.NET and C#

Tags: javascript

I need the uploaded message should be displayed in label once the file chosen. I tried the below code. But it does not work. Please advise.

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="fileUpload" runat="server" /><br />
<asp:Label ID="labelsuccess" runat="server" Text="uploaded" visible="false"></asp:Label>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#fileUpload').change(function () {
            var path = $(this).val();
             $('#labelsuccess').innertext
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Answer has been updated**

HTMLElement.innerText is a DOM property, while
.text() is the function used to get or set the text of matched elements through jQuery.

https://api.jquery.com/text/#text-text

> .text()
>
> Description: Get the combined text contents of each element in the set
> of matched elements, including their descendants.
>
> .text( text )
>
> Description: Set the content of each
> element in the set of matched elements to the specified text.

So in your original code

```
 $('#labelsuccess').innertext
```

You are calling some property that as far as I am concerned, does not exist. I expect `.innerText` to exist, but I am not sure since it is the $ (jQuery) object.

What you want to do to update the #labelsuccess classed objects is to call the .text function.

```
$('#labelsuccess').text(path)
```

Here I have a pure jQuery/html fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uboe41hr/.
Note that I have restructured the HTML, based on the usage of the jQuery `.on()` function. This function keeps observing the targeted element (in my example, that would be `#fileUploadParent`) for changes into one of its children (`#fileUpload`).

But, there are probably additional considerations based on the fact that you are using ASP.NET, so maybe you want to check the examples at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload?view=netframework-4.8.

Observing the examples in that last resource, I did not see jQuery integration, and it appears that it is ASP.NET's expectation that the interactive elements (in this case, the ones you want jQuery to operate on) be handled by native ASP.NET functions.

Comment: still I am not able to complete my task. As I have file upload button in repeater control.After choose each file the label text should be changed with the text uploaded.  My code: $('.mylabel.')text('uploaded').But this code update all the files.I want to update the label text after choosing each files.

Comment: You may have to update your answer to reflect what you are trying to do. If it is `$('.mylabel.')text('uploaded')`, then there is something wrong here. In your question, you make reference to `$('#labelsuccess')` being the target of the update that you want to make. If you do not understand it, please read about querySelector and querySelectorAll functions in JS, which is the bases of jQuery. In short, if you use #labelsuccess, you are targeting a single html element that has the id of 'labelsuccess'.